# Raising A Custom Error with Flask-Restful

Tags: flask, flask-restful

All, I'm trying to raise a custom error using Flask-Restful, following [the docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#define-custom-error-messages). For testing purposes, I've defined and registered the errors dictionary exactly link in the docs: `api = flask_restful.Api(app, errors=errors)`.

However, when I want to raise the custom error using (e.g.) `abort(409)` within the resource module, firebug reports:

> {
>       "message": "Conflict", 
>       "status": 409
>   }

This seems like the standard 409 error, nothing custom; from the docs, I would expect the custom error message- "A user with that username already exists."

I think I'm missing something regarding the raising of the error itself. Should I use the dictionary key in any way? Reviewing the Flask-Restful source code didn't help, though I tried.

Comment: Same here. If I defined 3 different errors for 400, how can I raise those errors? In the doc it says it saves try and catch in api function, but I don't see a clear way how that can be done.

Answer (score 20):

To define a message for a standard *HTTP status code* with **Flask-RESTful**, you must redefine one of the HTTP exceptions provided by [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), on which **Flask** is based.

Following your question, here is an example to override the [`Conflict` exception](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.Conflict):

```
errors = {
    'Conflict': {
        'message': "A user with that username already exists.",
        'status': 409,
    },
}

app = Flask(__name__)
api = flask_restful.Api(app, errors=errors)
```

Hence, every time you will call `abort(409)`, this will return a representation in the right mediatype, and with the defined message.

However, by using this method, in any place you will abort with a `409` status code, this will return a message about a user with a username that already exists. This is unlikely what you want when you call `abort(409)` in a view that deals with other resources than users.

So, I advise you to simply use the `abort` method of **Flask-RESTful** as follows, every time you want to provide a custom message:

```
from flask.ext.restful import abort

abort(409, description="A user with that username already exists.")
```

Generally speaking, extending Flask-RESTful by defining custom error messages is useful when you raise custom exceptions (with `raise()`, not `abort()`) which are not in the [HTTP exceptions](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/exceptions/#error-classes) provided by Werkzeug.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with the above: *** TypeError: abort() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @Kelvin make sure that you import the abort from flask and not from flask_restful. That was the reason for me that I received this error.

Comment: @Kelvin try abort(409, message="A user with that username already exists.")