# Flask-restful not handling errors

Tags: python-3.x, flask, exception, flask-restful

Whenever my code throws an exception the client gets error 500 internal server error.

```
errors = {
    'UserNotFoundException': {
        'message': 'User does not exist.',
        'status': 404,
    }
}


bp = Blueprint('users', __name__)
api = Api(bp, errors=errors)
```

I cannot throw `UserNotFoundException` from my routes without causing error 500. What I've defined in `errors` seems to be ignored.

Comment: Maybe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910503/raising-a-custom-error-with-flask-restful) helps. In general i would also recommend using the flask-restful `abort()` function for this purpose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flask: error\_handler for blueprints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768825/flask-error-handler-for-blueprints)